# Search layout quick action with lightning component issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components, search-layout, lightning-quickaction

I'm trying to create a quick action inside a search layout. This quick action calls a custom component.
The point is that when I click the new action
[image]

Allows me to create a that kind of quick action but then it doesn't display on the search layout.

**Is this some kind of salesforce bug or not possible functionality for now?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Adding a quick action of type Lightning Component is not possible yet in the search layout. You can add that quick action which is of type create a record. As a workaround, You can create a VF page and embed it to list button of type URL and add it to search layout.

Answer (score 0):

That is very frustrating and still not being possible.
Up vote here my friend
https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gde9aUAB/add-lightning-component-quick-actions-to-search-layouts